# Protractor E2E Tests on CircleCI using Saucelabs

Tags: angularjs, protractor, saucelabs, e2e-testing, circleci

I'm trying to get angular-phonecat e2e tests running on Circleci using Saucelabs.

I've forked this project:

https://github.com/circleci/angular-phonecat

and modified the circle.yml according to this documentation:

docs.saucelabs.com/ci-integrations/circleci/

The other files are not changed.

The e2e tests pass on Circleci. But in Saucelabs I'm not seeing any tests. The tunnel is beeing opened and closed correctly (see attached stdout_cd_11281). I also see it on Saucelabs opening and closing. And the tests are also beeing executed successfully (see attached stdout_npm_11891.txt). But no test are recorded on Saucelabs.

The tests run through on circle regardless if I open the tunnel or not, so I suspect, that the tunnel is not beeing used.

What do I need to configure in order that circle uses the tunnel to run the tests on saucelabs? 
Here's my forked and modified anguar-phonecat project:

https://github.com/alphatools/angular-phonecat

I Appreciate your help! Thanks.

circle.yml

```
machine:
  node:
    version:
      0.10.28
dependencies:
  post:
    - wget https://saucelabs.com/downloads/sc-latest-linux.tar.gz
    - tar -xzf sc-latest-linux.tar.gz

test:
  override:
    - npm run test-single-run
    - cd sc-*-linux && ./bin/sc --user $SAUCE_USERNAME --api-key $SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY --readyfile ~/sauce_is_ready:
        background: true
    # Wait for tunnel to be ready
    - while [ ! -e ~/sauce_is_ready ]; do sleep 1; done
    - npm start:
        background: true
    - sleep 5
    - npm run protractor
  post:
    - killall --wait sc  # wait for Sauce Connect to close the tunnel
```

stdout_cd_11281.txt:

```
10 Oct 22:33:28 - Sauce Connect 4.3, build 1283 399e76d
10 Oct 22:33:28 - Using CA certificate bundle /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt.
10 Oct 22:33:28 - Using no proxy for connecting to Sauce Labs REST API.
10 Oct 22:33:29 - **********************************************************
10 Oct 22:33:29 - A newer version of Sauce Connect (build 1757) is available!
10 Oct 22:33:29 - Download it here:
10 Oct 22:33:29 - https://saucelabs.com/downloads/sc-4.3.11-linux.tar.gz
10 Oct 22:33:29 - **********************************************************
10 Oct 22:33:30 - Started scproxy on port 45650.
10 Oct 22:33:30 - Please wait for 'you may start your tests' to start your tests.
10 Oct 22:33:30 - Starting secure remote tunnel VM...
10 Oct 22:33:33 - Secure remote tunnel VM provisioned.
10 Oct 22:33:33 - Tunnel ID: 8569af871fff44ffbbca7a2e1cf0024f
10 Oct 22:33:34 - Secure remote tunnel VM is now: booting
10 Oct 22:33:50 - Secure remote tunnel VM is now: running
10 Oct 22:33:50 - Remote tunnel host is: maki78195.miso.saucelabs.com
10 Oct 22:33:50 - Using no proxy for connecting to tunnel VM.
10 Oct 22:33:50 - Starting Selenium listener...
10 Oct 22:33:50 - Establishing secure TLS connection to tunnel...
10 Oct 22:33:50 - Selenium listener started on port 4445.
10 Oct 22:33:52 - Sauce Connect is up, you may start your tests.
10 Oct 22:33:52 - Connection established.
10 Oct 22:34:21 - Cleaning up.
10 Oct 22:34:21 - Finished! Deleting tunnel.
10 Oct 22:34:22 - Overlapping domain: sauce-connect.proxy, removing tunnel 8569af871fff44ffbbca7a2e1cf0024f.
10 Oct 22:34:25 - Goodbye.
```

stdout_npm_11891.txt:

```
> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 prestart /home/ubuntu/angular-phonecat
> npm install
> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 postinstall /home/ubuntu/angular-phonecat
> bower install
> angular-phonecat@0.0.0 start /home/ubuntu/angular-phonecat
> http-server -p 8000
[33mStarting up http-server, serving [39m[36m./[39m[33m on port: [39m[36m8000[39m
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/index.html[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/css/app.css[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/css/animations.css[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/js/app.js[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/js/animations.js[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/js/controllers.js[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/js/filters.js[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/js/services.js[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/favicon.ico[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/partials/phone-list.html[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/phones/phones.json[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/motorola-xoom-with-wi-fi.0.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/motorola-xoom.0.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/motorola-atrix-4g.0.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/dell-streak-7.0.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/samsung-gem.0.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/dell-venue.0.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/nexus-s.0.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/lg-axis.0.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/samsung-galaxy-tab.0.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/samsung-showcase-a-galaxy-s-phone.0.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/droid-2-global-by-motorola.0.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/droid-pro-by-motorola.0.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/motorola-bravo-with-motoblur.0.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/motorola-defy-with-motoblur.0.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/t-mobile-mytouch-4g.0.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/samsung-mesmerize-a-galaxy-s-phone.0.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/sanyo-zio.0.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/samsung-transform.0.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/t-mobile-g2.0.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:10 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/motorola-charm-with-motoblur.0.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:16 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/partials/phone-detail.html[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:16 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/phones/nexus-s.json[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:16 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/nexus-s.1.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:16 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/nexus-s.2.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
[Sat, 10 Oct 2015 22:34:16 GMT] "[36mGET[39m [36m/app/img/phones/nexus-s.3.jpg[39m" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36"
```